# Twitter as feed reader

Tags: twitter, feeds

Is it possible to use Twitter as a feed reader?

I am not interested in writing messages to other people or giving my opinion on some topic, but I am interested in being updated on some people, websites and so on.

I prefer to not be intercepted by people I know (but this is not so important).

Comment: You can feasibly make your account private but follow several others to provide you with what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is a common practice to use Twitter for reading only.

You can create a new private account with a random username (not anything that can be linked to you), follow the accounts you're interested in, and do not accept any follower requests.

If you're particularly concerned about privacy, do this with a separate email account (not used for anything else) to reduce the chances  of your account coming up in someone's "Friends suggestions" when they [upload their contacts to Twitter](https://support.twitter.com/articles/101002).

People whom you follow will still be notified that your account  follows them,  but it won't tell them much if they don't recognize the username.

Comment: So the only shrewdness are to choose a nickname not linked to me and do not accept any follower requests?

Comment: This is if you want to maintain incognito status. If you don't care about being recognized, you wouldn't need these either: just create an account and use it for reading, without posting anything.